# How to represent a Carriage return (\r, ^M) as part of text over serial

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu, serial, arduino

I am trying to send a message including carriage returns (represented without pressing enter) over a serial connection.  It works if i press enter with an open serial connection, but I have not found a way to represent the carriage return character successfully within the message body.

For example, the following works either opening a serial connection to my Arduino over USB (screen /dev/tty.usbmodemFA1331 9600) or using the Arduino serial monitor:

SIOP v1.0 OUTPUT
ContentType: Text/UTF-8
Value: "Hello World!"
/END

(note that i enter one line at a time and press enter on my keyboard after each line).

But the following attempts do not:

- SIOP v1.0 OUTPUT\rContentType: Text/UTF-8\rValue: "Hello
  slashr!"\r/END
- SIOP v1.0 OUTPUT^MContentType: Text/UTF-8^MValue:
  "Hello m!"^M/END
- SIOP v1.0 OUTPUT/rContentType: Text/UTF-80x0DValue:
  "Hello World!"0x0D/END

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you should be sending a carriage return (0x0D), rather than a newline (which may be any of 0x0D, 0x0A, or both together)?

Comment: Special text notation such as "\r" need to be converted into a single control character (i.e. a byte value) by an input or output program (e.g. by the compiler for **printf()** strings).  This does not happen automatically or automagically.  Is there a scan and convert software in your situation (it's most likely that you do not)?

Comment: Yes converting them into a single byte value is exactly what I want to do.  I was hoping there was an escape sequence that informed the serial terminal that I wanted to send the CR.  I am testing sending messages to multiple devices and the massages have multiple lines each.  Trying to simplify the process so i do not have to enter each line but can send it all together.  @Jeff yes, CR is what the devices are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It works if i press enter with an open serial connection, but I have not found a way to represent the carriage return character successfully within the message body.

Special text notation such as "\r" would have to be converted into a single control character (i.e. a byte value) by an input or output program (e.g. by the compiler for **printf()** strings).
This does not happen automatically or automagically.
Certainly terminal emulation programs such as **screen** do not recognize or perform such conversions on the input text.

What you seem to be trying to do is misguided.
The typical terminal emulation programs such as **minicom** (and probably **screen** but I'm not positive since I've never used it) transmit the literal characters as they are entered.
A terminal program could have a line (or block) mode where local line editing is possible, and the (buffered) line (or block) of text is only transmitted after `Enter` or some `SEND` key is pressed.  But that is probably not the operational mode you are using.

The typical terminal emulation program operates in character mode rather than line/block mode. (Note that this is distinct from termios or canonical versus raw modes.)
So trying to *"represent the carriage return character ... within the message body"* (as you type on the keyboard) simply means that you're trying to inhibit the visible movement of the *local* cursor from being performed.  Your goal accomplishes nothing else, because the transmission of the characters will not be deferred (in the current operational mode).

You could confirm the futility of what you're trying to accomplish by attaching an oscilloscope or just another terminal.  You should be able to verify that your "messages" are output character/byte at a time as typed, and not as a "line" or message block.

If you still insist on sending your messages as one block of text, **minicom** has the capability of sending a plain text file.

Comment: Thank you for your post, I was able to achieve my goal using minicom!